# unEven an array, like the concatAll function

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have this 2 Arrays representing the same data:

```
array1 = [
  {name: "max", age: 30},
  {name: "paul"},
  {name: "paul.Jack", age: 25},
  {name: "max.David"},
  {name: "max.Sylvia", age: 27},
  {name: "paul.Jack.Ned"},
  {name: "paul.Jack.Mike"},
  {name: "max.David.Jeff"},
  {name: "max.Sylvia.Anna", age: 5},
  {name: "max.David.Buffy"},
  {name: "max.Sylvia.Craig"},
  {name: "max.Sylvia.Robin"}
];
array2 = [
    {
      name: "max",
      age: 30,
      children: [
        {
          name: "Sylvia",
          age: 27,
          children: [
            {name: "Anna", age: 5},
            {name: "Craig"},
            {name: "Robin"}
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "David",
          children: [
            {name: "Jeff"},
            {name: "Buffy"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "paul",
      children: [
        {
          name: "Jack",
          age: 25,
          children: [
            {name: "Ned"},
            {name: "Mike"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

my objective is to have a function unEven which transform the array1 to the array2, I'm using lodash to do this here's where I'm now:
To *`unEven`* array1 to array2 the tracking property in this case 'name' contain the information about where in the new array this item should be pushed check this [js bin](http://jsbin.com/welesoqige/2/edit?js,console), this work for 3 level nested array but my goal is to have it unEven arrays without limit of their nesting level, that's where I'm stuck.
The unEven function will be like the concatAll function presented in this [video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-create-an-array-concatall-method).
Here's the unEven function:

```
Array.prototype.unEven = function (trackingProperty, children, resultArray) {
  var newItem, prop, index, parent, subParent, subParentIndex;
  resultArray = resultArray || [];
  this.forEach(function (item) {
    newItem = lodash.omit(item, trackingProperty);
    prop    = lodash.pick(item, trackingProperty);
    if (prop[trackingProperty].indexOf('.') === -1) {
      resultArray.push(item);
    } else {
      newItem[trackingProperty] = prop[trackingProperty].split(".");
      parent = {};
      parent[trackingProperty] = newItem[trackingProperty][0];
      index = lodash.indexOf(resultArray, lodash.find(resultArray, parent));
      if (newItem[trackingProperty].length === 2) {
        newItem[trackingProperty] = newItem[trackingProperty][1];
        if (!Array.isArray(resultArray[index][children])) {
          resultArray[index][children] = [];
        }
        resultArray[index][children].push(newItem);
      } else if (newItem[trackingProperty].length === 3) {
        subParent = {};
        subParent[trackingProperty] = newItem[trackingProperty][1];
        subParentIndex = lodash.indexOf(resultArray[index][children], lodash.find(resultArray[index][children], subParent));
        newItem[trackingProperty]   = newItem[trackingProperty][2];
        if (!Array.isArray(resultArray[index][children][subParentIndex][children])) {
          resultArray[index][children][subParentIndex][children] = [];
        }
        resultArray[index][children][subParentIndex][children].push(newItem);
      }
    }
  });
  return resultArray;
};
```

To give my use case for this I'm trying to make a [d3js tree layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout) of [angular ui router](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router) in my application that will be generated from the routes JSON file since I make the routes in a JSON file.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery.extend ??? See here: http://jsbin.com/pujuniweje/1/edit?js,console

Comment: That doesn't do what I want I want to transform array1 to be array2 not extend them or merge them together.
check the http://jsbin.com/welesoqige/2/edit?js,console that I provided it doesn't give the same output that yours gives.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I did not understand well this unEven thing. However You said that there's a tracking property with which you map objects from array2, so in other words you need to take the children of the element with name and add them to the current object.

The code I provided did what you wanted for the one element where name is max.
Here's a pastebin (the first object is yours the second is mine): http://pastebin.com/kEsZJn1Q

Comment: what I need is to take the first array1 and give it to a function that return the array2, your function takes the 2 arrays and merge them, and both arrays are the same here http://pastebin.com/kEsZJn1Q just the order of items is changed, like this:
`array2 = array1.unEven('name', 'children');`
probably `unflatten` is more suitable name for this function.

Comment: I finally understood the problem and spent some time thinking but with no success. However I think you may think about getting each child in it's own object (for example: {name: "Craig", parent:"Sylvia"}) and then populate the children field with objects where the parent is equal to the name field, for this to work the names in your example has to be unique or you can add indexes and work with indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a lodash-heavy solution that I think does what you want.  You can skip the cloning if you don't care about mutating the original array, and skip the sorting if you always have children after their parents in the original array.

```
function unEven(array1) {
     _(_.clone(array1, true)) //begin chaining syntax, with cloned array
    .each(function(person) {
        person.name = person.name.split(".") //replace name with array of names
    })
    .sortBy(function(person) {return person.name.length}) //sort so that we handle children after parents
    .reduce(function(result, person) {
        var parentArray = result;
        var name = person.name.pop() //their actual name is the last one in the list
        _.each(person.name, function(parentName) { //loop through parent names to find the proper array to add to
            var parent = _.find(parentArray, {name: parentName});
            if(!parent) throw new Error(name + " has non-existent parent "+parentName);
            parentArray = parent.children = parent.children || []
        })
        person.name = name; //return name back to just being their name
        parentArray.push(person);
        return result;
    }, []) //reduce ends chaining syntax; so no need for .value
}
```